# converting string into binary integer in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a string into a binary integer:

```
string = "0b011" 
i = int(string)
```

But this code raises a `ValueError`. However, the following code works fine:

```
i = int(0b011)
```

But here I've passed a binary literal, not a string. How do I convert a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
string = '0b011'
i = int(string, 2) # value of i is 3
```

It uses the built-in procedure [int()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) with the optional base parameter, which indicates the base to be used in the conversion - two in this case, from the documentation:

> The base parameter gives the base for the conversion (which is 10 by default) and may be any integer in the range [2, 36], or zero. If base is zero, the proper radix is determined based on the contents of string; the interpretation is the same as for integer literals.

Answer (score 2):

use the second optional argument(base), to tell `int()` that the string is of `base 2`:

```
int(str[,base])

>>> string = "0b011"
>>> int(string,2)
3
```

Comment: What does the second argument do?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval("0b011")
3
```